# Should I pay someone to help me with an open source project?

Tags: java

Anyone have suggestions on how to get development help on an open-source project?
I've got some funding but not enough to hire someone yet.

I've been considering offering 'bounties' for specific tasks.
But the tasks aren't too big - so writing up the task, sizing it, posting it, evaluating the work, and paying the bounty would probably take as long as the development would.
There's just a bunch to do!

Another idea was to pay 10 people to create a project using the framework, then write-up a one page document on ways to improve it.
It's mostly Java/Spring and React js, so it would be helpful to target developers with those skills - but I'd also like feedback from others.

This is the framework I'm referring to -
https://github.com/savantly-net/sprout-platform

Comment: You can raise an issue with detail what you want from someone with a label "help-wanted". It might help you.

Comment: It seems like your question is more about how to efficiently offer bounties for a FLOSS project, rather than whether you should or not. I think there are some sites that let you offer a bounty on any Github issue - that makes it really simple. Of course you still have to write what the feature request is.